# DB Cleanup on Session timeout and logout

Tags: session, servlets, session-timeout

Just a quick question. On login I put every user into a db because one time only one user can log in with the same username and password. If this user is already in the db I dont let the user in. When the user logs out I clear the dB table and invalidate the session in a Servlet.
Now if the user forgot to logout, the session obviously will be expired at eg. 20 minutes so
In web.xml I created this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.servlets.dbclean</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This dbclean class then implements `HttpSessionListener` and on the `sessionDestroyed` method I clear up the db. 
My question: is it enough to have this db cleanup happen only here, because when the user logs out manually the session will be invalidated and this method will be called or should I clean up the db at the `/doLogout` Servlet and rely on this Listener when the user forgot to log out? So is it a save way to use only this Listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listener will be triggered when the session is invalidated - either by timeout or by calling `invalidate()`

If you don't need to support clustering, you can simply store the logged user in a `Set` inside the `ServletContext` (do it in on `sessionCreated(..)`, and then remove it from that Set in `sessionDestroyed(..)`. No need to go to the database - it can all stay in memory. (Using session replication you can do this in a cluster as well)